# Updated VirtIO SCSI driver on my Windows 2012 R2, and now only boots into recovery. How to recover?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, qemu, hetzner, virtio

I have a Hetzner W2012 R2 Cloud VM, and I updated the VirtIO `vioscsi` driver on it. Now it only boots into recovery mode and I cannot access the C-drive even from command prompt.

Is there any way to save this VM or is it a goner?
I have no (recent) snapshot of it :(

I can mount the old previous VirtIO ISO, but how can I reinstall the old driver when I have no access to the C-drive?

**Update 1**:
Am able to get access to the C-drive with `drvload vioscsci.inf`.
Still trying to figure out how to reinstall the old drivers.

**Update 2**
I used `dism /image:e:\ /add-driver /driver:vioscsi.inf` to add the driver but it still won't boot.

**Update 3**
Startup repair gives error `0x490`.

No clue what to do next or how to even troubleshoot why it is not booting.

**Update 4**

**It appears all my system drivers have become unsigned**. Disabling driver signature enforcement allowed the system to finally boot.

Do not know why this happened. It appears I will have to do a full reinstall, but at least I got back access to the VM now.

Comment: Yes. I also made sure to uninstall all other versions of vioscsi in case it was still loading something incorrectly. Didn't help either.

Comment: Change the VM to use Sata/ahci instead of virtio, add an extra disk device with virtio, hopefully windows starts and you can fix the drivers and verify on new disk, shutdown and restore settings.

Comment: @NiKiZe That might fix it, but as far as I know you can't change the startup parameters on Hetzner Cloud VMs. At least I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Looks like all my drivers became unsigned. I was able to get into the VM by disabling signature enforcement.

Comment: Ok. I will post it as an answer if I can't figure out how to fix the signatures. Still trying to figure out that part, but I may throw in the towel soon.

Answer (score 2):

**1: Disable driver signature enforcement**

After much investigation, all system drivers had become unsigned. Cause unknown (possibly drive corruption).

To access the VM I needed to boot without driver signature enforcement.
To do that, first activate the boot menu from Windows Recovery:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes
```

Then reboot, press F8 and choose to boot without enforcement.

**2: Restore missing security catalogs**

For some reason all files in

```
C:\Windows\System32\catroot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}
```

...had disappeared. I happened to have a `catroot_old` folder in `System32`, so I copied the files from there back into `catroot`. Using any previous backup would probably have worked too.

This change allowed me to boot normally again.